# Distributions and p-values in python

Tags: python, statistics, distribution

I have a big list of numbers, and I would like to create a distribution out of this data, plot it, then find the p-value for every number in my list with regards to the distribution.

Is it possible to do this in python? I can't find it in the matplotlib documentation. Should i be using something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the searchsorted function from the numpy module, which will give you the order of a set of values in an ordered array. you can then transform it to a pvalue just by renormalizing it to the dimension of the original array:

```
data = sorted(rand(10))
new_data = rand(5)
pvals = searchsorted(data,new_data)*1./len(data)
print pvals
#array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9])
```

Well, in fact if you want the pvalues of the original number you don't need any special function at all: the pvalues are just the order in the sorted dataset divided by it's lenght.
If you need the pvalues of new values in respect to your original ones, you can use the snippet I gave you

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to look into the [`stats`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) module of `scipy`; it offers numerous statistical functions for things like this. For plotting, I would still use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/).